# Formatting a table using Html helper function in MVC 3 Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

Using the following:

- MVC 3
- VB.NET
- RAZOR VIEW engine
- Html Helper Class

In my application I have a list(of string) that is sent to a view and is displayed. I am trying to have this display in a table format that is no more than 8 columns wide to many rows long. I have wrote a custom helper class to handle this but the view is showing the raw html code with the email addresses but its not rendering as a table with the rows and such.. Any ideas how to correct this.. Below is the helper class, the template, and finally the view.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Public Module TableHelper
<Extension()> _
Public Function CreateEmailTable(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, ByVal emaillist As List(Of String)) As MvcHtmlString
    Dim htmlDisplayer As String = Table()
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    For Each item In emaillist
        If counter = 0 Then
            htmlDisplayer = htmlDisplayer + NRow()
        End If
        counter += 1
        If Not counter >= 8 Then
            htmlDisplayer = htmlDisplayer + Ntd(item)
        Else
            counter = 0
            htmlDisplayer = htmlDisplayer + CRow()
        End If
    Next
    htmlDisplayer = htmlDisplayer + CTable()
    Dim x As MvcHtmlString = MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlDisplayer)
    Return x
End Function
Public Function Table() As String
    Return String.Format("<table>")
End Function
Public Function CTable() As String
    Return String.Format("</table>")
End Function
Public Function NRow() As String
    Return String.Format("<tr>")
End Function
Public Function CRow() As String
    Return String.Format("</tr>")
End Function
Public Function Ntd(ByVal text As String) As String
    Return String.Format("<td>{0}</td>", text)
End Function
End Module
```

The Template View is:

```
@ModelTYPE List(Of String)
@Html.CreateEmailTable(Model)
```

And Finally the view is:

```
Modeltype xxxxxxxxx.EmailsVM
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Mass Emails Sent"
End Code
@Using Html.BeginForm
@<fieldset>
<p>
@Html.Partial("_EmailsVM", Model.failEmList)
</p>
</fieldset>
End Using
```

And this is a snippet of what view page source is showing when I look at it in a browser:

```
  &lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;xxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.net; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;xxxxx.xxxxxxxx@xxxxx; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;
```

As can be seen its the html markup is losing its formating that browsers pick up on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET strings are HTML encoded by default. You can either use `Html.Raw()` to print the raw HTML, or have it return an `MvcHtmlString`, which the MVC engine knows is already encoded and shouldn't encode again.

Reference: [MvcHtmlString Class - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx)

Comment: Thanks much man.. I started to get on to that when I realized the function was returning as string. Didn't know there what as MvcHtmlString Class until Now... For all that run into this I have edited the helper function above to show the working solution..